# Get Count of users based on date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have simple table where i store userID, UserName, Email, RegistrationDate ...

`RegistrationDate` is `DateTime` Datatype

When i to to get the count of users for each date it get me 1 for each row as it each row has a unique dateTime stamp.

```
SELECT DATEPART(dd, RegistrationDate) AS DD, COUNT(userID)   
FROM USER_Table 
GROUP BY RegistrationDate 
order by RegistrationDate DESC
```

ABove query get me each 100 rows if i have 100 users registered.

I want to get count based on date. i tried different thing but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
SELECT Cast(RegistrationDate AS DATE),
       Count(userID)
FROM   User_Table
GROUP  BY Cast(RegistrationDate AS DATE)
ORDER  BY Cast(RegistrationDate AS DATE)DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by `CAST(RegistrationDate as Date)`

```
SELECT CAST(RegistrationDate as Date) AS [Date], COUNT(userID)   
FROM USER_Table 
GROUP BY CAST(RegistrationDate as Date)
order by CAST(RegistrationDate as Date) DESC
```

Comment: This will group by day, not date. So October 1st will get grouped with November 1st, December 1st etc.

Comment: still won't  work. you need to cast the order by column as well

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cast(RegistrationDate as Date) AS DD, COUNT(userID)   
FROM USER_Table 
GROUP BY cast(RegistrationDate as Date)
order by cast(RegistrationDate as Date) DESC
```